# Why my css file not loading but download when i have a different ?xxxxx

Tags: html, css

use sysfony framework

1. [image]
2. but when I change the `/assets/v2/css/es-icon.css?6.17.1.1`
   `/assets/v2/css/es-icon.css?2.17.1.1`

Comment: It's because it's being cached by your browser. The whole purpose of the `?xxxx` is to force the browser to re-download those css files.

Comment: It is version control. If the file needs to be forced for download if there are changes in the file.

Comment: it download a bootstrap.css file to my computer, not request the file again. my english is bad, sorry.